# 'event' has no "key" attribute

Tags: python, pygame

[image]  ** this is a part of a code  **

```
    def _cheak_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys(exit)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True
            
            elif event.key == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False
```

**
error shows that:
38, in _cheak_events
elif event.key == pygame.KEYDOWN:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all `event.key` with `event.type`

Comment: but not all event.key . only one i have changed in ``` elif event.key == pygame.KEYUP ``` to ``` elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP  ```